# gdb-multiarch cannot recognize my arm binary file

Tags: gdb

I want to use gdb-multiarch to remote debug arm code running in qemu. Below is my `mk` script:

```
ARM=arm-none-eabi
QEMU=qemu-system-arm

$ARM-as -o ts.o ts.s -g
$ARM-ld -T t.ld -o t.elf ts.o
$ARM-nm t.elf
$ARM-objcopy -O binary t.elf t.bin

dd if=t.bin of=flash.bin bs=4096 conv=notrunc

$QEMU -s -S -M realview-pbx-a9 -kernel t.bin -nographic -serial /dev/null
```

however, when I type `gdb-multiarch ./t.bin`, it shows `"t.bin": not in executable format: file format not recognized`.

The output of `file t.bin` is : `t.bin: data`.

What should I do to correctly debug `t.bin` file?